# Python 3 - number of letters in an encoded string

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.4, hebrew

I would like to get the number of letters in a given string.
However, len(txt) returns the number of letters in the unicode form (I guess), but the actual number of letters is less then what I get.

for example:

```
txt = שלום וברכה
len(txt)   # returns something different then 10
```

I saw a solution for python 2 using `string.decode` , which is not available in python 3 - and I'm not sure it is the appropriate answer for me.
By the way, the encoding for the string is `cp862`.

EDIT: more details:
I read from a text file using

```
with open(path, "r",  encoding="cp862") as textFile:
```

this is the output of the line I read when I print it

```
╫¬╫ñ╫¿╫ש╫ר ╫£╫ª╫ץ╫¥: ╫¢╫ת ╫¬╫ª╫£╫ק╫ץ ╫נ╫¬ ╫¢╫ש╫ñ╫ץ╫¿
```

The length is 52.
The real line is: תפריט לצום: כך תצלחו את כיפור
and the real the length is 29

Comment: On repl.it I get: >len("שלום וברכה") => 10. Maybe you could provide more details about your platform and python version.

Comment: I get this:
`>>> len('שלום וברכה')
>>>10`

Comment: At the very least provide actual valid code with which to reproduce the issue. This sample isn't even syntactically valid.

Comment: _"By the way, the encoding for the string is 'cp862'."_ In python3 all strings are UTF-8 by default, what do you mean with "the string is cp862" ?

Comment: Sorry all for the confusion. I edited my question to shed more light on it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Saving this text as "MS-DOS Hebrew" into a file and then opening and printing it with the code you show results in proper Hebrew output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are opening the file with the wrong encoding scheme, here is a demonstration:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'
>>> 
>>> s = '╫¬╫ñ╫¿╫ש╫ר ╫£╫ª╫ץ╫¥: ╫¢╫ת ╫¬╫ª╫£╫ק╫ץ ╫נ╫¬ ╫¢╫ש╫ñ╫ץ╫¿'
>>> len(s)
52
>>>
>>> s = s.encode('cp862').decode('utf-8')
'תפריט לצום: כך תצלחו את כיפור'
>>> len(s)
29
```

Try to open it with default encoding (utf-8).

Comment: @RonU...If you are happy with this answer...consider accepting it.